# Reachability responding with wrong status code in iOS 7 iphone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iphone-5, reachability

I am facing weird problem on iPhone 5 with iOS 7, i have tested same code with other devices like iPad1, 2, 3 and iPhone 4, 4s etc. with different iOS combination including iOS 7.

**Problem :**

When i turn on airplane mode i do get reachability notification as expected with status `NotReachable` but immediately after that app receives notification with status code `ReachableViaWWAN` which is not expected.

**Code :**

```
+(BOOL)checkReachability
{
    Reachability* internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus)

    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            DebugLog(@"The internet is down.");
            return NO;
            break;
        }
        default:
            return YES;
            break;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I added log before switch which is returning status as `ReachableViaWWAN` in airplane mode..

**Possible workaround could be:**

Add case for `ReachableViaWWAN` and check host reachable in that case. And return BOOL value accordingly.

Anyone faced similar problem ?? i have searched but haven't found similar scenario.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. The solution is to check the flag *isConnectionRequired*. The documentation says:

> WWAN may be available, but not active until a connection has been established.

#### Code

```
BOOL isServerAvailable;
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

if ((reachability.isConnectionRequired) || (NotReachable == reachability.currentReachabilityStatus)) {
    isServerAvailable = NO;

} else if((ReachableViaWiFi == reachability.currentReachabilityStatus) || (ReachableViaWWAN == reachability.currentReachabilityStatus)){
    isServerAvailable = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The old Reachability files are no good. Apple has updated their reachability files.

Check here.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Download here.

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Reachability.zip

Comment: Using the latest code from Apple solved WWAN issues for me. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it for me too

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem and found a [solution here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=942439). Basically for some reason it's possible to get `ReachableViaWWAN` even when in airplane mode. However, there's another flag that will indicate whether a connection must first be established. This is the `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired` flag which has a nice helper method in the Reachability class called `connectionRequired`

Answer (score 0):

Reachability classes can give strange results if you are using the Network Link Conditioner tool provided by Apple.

Comment: Please add your post as a comment if it is not intended at answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)handleReachability:(Reachability *)reachability
{
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL connectionRequired = [reachability connectionRequired];
    NSString* statusString = @"";

    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {

            if (connectionRequired) {
                [TSMessage setDefaultViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];

                [TSMessage showNotificationWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Something failed", nil)
                                            subtitle:NSLocalizedString(@"The internet connection seems to be down. Please check that!", nil)
                                                type:TSMessageNotificationTypeError];
            }

            connectionRequired = NO;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;


    }

}
```